# AWS iam.deleteAccessKey not reliable in Node10 Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

Why can't I `await` [iam.deleteAccessKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html#deleteAccessKey-property)?

I have even tried building a zip file with `aws-sdk@2.625.0` in it and still get the same results.

The problem is that a key is only successfully deleted every other time the lambda is called.

I haven't yet made a stripped down code sample (I'm helping another developer with this problem), but here is the basic concept:

```js
/********************************************************
This is not a working code sample.
I'm stuck in meetings and haven't been able to work on
this. These are just a few excerpts from the many things
I've tried.
********************************************************/

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
//AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(null)
var iam = new AWS.IAM({ apiVersion: '2010-05-08' })

const params = { AccessKeyId: `${id}`, UserName: `${username}` }
await iam.deleteAccessKey(params).promise()
console.log('done')
```

I'm much more comfortable with Python than Node, but even a few of our Node masters are stumped. I didn't think I had to do anything special to get access to promises in [modern] NodeJS10, but I tried a few old school things (from the references below) just in case. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

**I'll try to get a good complete example function added, but this is just to get the conversation started since I can find no questions on the matter.**

Here is a series of references that I find thoroughly confusing:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

PS: I expect to get flamed for this post. I'm willing to edit it to refocus it once I learn more about the nature of this odd behavior. Please be constructive.

Comment: You need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I intend to. I just haven't had time. It's not my code. It's not for me. When I first tried to create an MCVE, I couldn't recreate it. I haven't had time to help this developer with this today. And the reason I'm doing this for her is that every time she tries to ask a question on here, she gets attacked because English is not her first language. It's amazing that I am getting down votes even with that comment in the code block.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm right, your sample of code isn't in a function. Make sure to wrap it around an `async` function, or use `.then`

Example with `async`:

```js
..startup code

async function myFunction() {
  await iam.deleteAccessKey(params).promise()
  console.log("done")
}
```

Example with `then`:

```
..startup code

iam.deleteAccessKey(params).promise().then(() => console.log("done"))
```

If you want to learn more, [Use this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Comment: Yes what I posted was a series of excerpts. The code is currently way too complex and I'm hoping to write a concise example if I can get any time between meetings.